# Loading a class from Maven dependency to my ClassLoader

Tags: java, reflection

I have a simple Java proyect where I want load a class from one of my Maven dependencies. I am using this code:

```
ClassLoader currentThreadClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
ClassLoader currentClassClassLoader = TestGeneratorApplication.class.getClassLoader();
ClassLoader sysClassloader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

String className = "My Class qualified name from my maven dependency";

Class<?> targetClass    = ReflectionUtils.forName(className, currentThreadClassLoader);
Class<?> targetClass2   = ReflectionUtils.forName(className, currentClassClassLoader);
Class<?> targetClass3   = ReflectionUtils.forName(className, sysClassloader);
```

The three ClassLoaders where I am searching gives me the same message (**Could not get type for name ... ClassNotFoundException**)

I don't know where search this class when I executed my method.

My maven dependency is a war defined like a normal  in the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartefactid</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0-2</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried this with building a jar of your project rather than war?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `Reflections.class.getClassLoader()` as your classloader.

```
ReflectionUtils.forName(className, Reflections.class.getClassLoader());
```

BTW  classLoaders param is optional and you can omit it like follows:

```
ReflectionUtils.forName(className)
```

> if optional ClassLoaders are not specified, then both
>   ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader() and
>   ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader() are used

[link](https://static.javadoc.io/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.10/org/reflections/ReflectionUtils.html#forName-java.lang.String-java.lang.ClassLoader...-)

Comment: I tried with Reflections.class.getClassLoader() and without optiona params and none of these options find my class.